# CSS Problem with Google Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

CSS Problem with Google Chrome and Safari

http://cart-v2-demo-2.fasttrackonline.co.uk/

I have tested the CSS in IE and Firefox and it renders as I would expect.

However, under Safari and Chrome a gap appears below the nav items in the main menu.

I'd appreciate any advice, please!

Thanks,
Jenny

Comment: Could you include a screenshot? The site looks fine to me (Google Chrome, runnning Windows 7)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the line-height: 40px you have in your #navMenu.
However, you have a mess there of ul and li elements. There should be simplified to a single ul and a list of li elements.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a `<br>` element to `clear float`?

Try replacing:

```
<br style="clear:both;font-size:0;line-height:0;height:0;">
```

With:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Making that change with Chrome Inspector at least fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but when I tried that change it broke the styling in IE and Firefox.